# Download Request - iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, download

I am trying to create an app where the user clicks on a download link through a UIWebView and it will present a pop-up saying "do you want to download this file". I just don't know how to get the download request when the user taps on a download link. If anyone knows how to do this please leave a reply.

thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`-[<UIWebViewDelegate> webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:]`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:)

The `request` parameter will have all the info about the URL that the request is for, and the `navigationType` parameter tells you how this request was initiated (a link was tapped, a form was submitted, something else, etc).